# Can I change as400 data area with c#

Tags: java, c#, db2, code-conversion

I have been asked if I can turn a java program into c#.

In the java program it reads and edits the data area

```
//get the value for the sysavail dtaara
String dtaara_path = "/QSYS.LIB/QGPL.LIB/SYSAVAIL.DTAARA";
QSYSObjectPathName path = new QSYSObjectPathName(dtaara_path);
CharacterDataArea dataArea = new CharacterDataArea(as400, path.getPath());

String setDataArea;

setDataArea = dataArea.read();

//if system available run
if(setDataArea.contains("Y")) {
    dataArea.write("IMAGE LOAD  ");
    //other stuff
}
```

I've used the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries to call programs but never to write to a data area. How can I write and read the data area using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries?

Comment: [Asking a yes or no question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) isn't likely to garner you a great response, and [simply asking if someone can find you a library is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please include specific problems or questions before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to AS400 using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336646/connect-to-as400-using-net)