# How to connect using odbc to as400 for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, odbc, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to connect to a AS400 server using ODBC driver via vb.net application but the problem is that I am trying to fill a dataset and whenever I want to display the data I don't find any thing

This is my code:

````
    Dim cn As OdbcConnection
    Dim cm As OdbcCommand
    Dim dm As OdbcDataAdapter


    Sub ConnServer()
        Try
            cn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=AS400_CA;UID=root;PWD=*****;")
            cn.Open()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Ecriture Comptable")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Function GetData(query As String) As DataTable
        Try

            cn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=AS400_CA;UID=root;PWD=*****;")
            Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(query, cn)

            cn.Open()

            Dim ds = New DataSet()
            cmd.Connection = cn
            dm.SelectCommand = cmd
            dm.Fill(ds, "table")
            Dim data = ds.Tables("table")
            cn.Close()
            Return data
        Catch ex As Exception
            con.Close()
            Return New DataTable()
        End Try
    End Function
```
````

Comment: Did you check if the GetData ends in an exception? This code cannot tell you if there is an error or if the query produces an empty table

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336646/connect-to-as400-using-net

Comment: Have you at least put a breakpoint in the Catch block of GetData?  Also in your catch, you've got con.Close().  Where does con come from, think it's cn everywhere else.  Your code might also benefit from a "Using" statement which will help you manage the connections

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what provider you are using. Check https://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400/ to check your connection string. I do not see a connection string that matches the syntax of your string.

I have no idea of select strings in AS400 so I just used a standard Sql string. Put your try/catch in the UI code so you can show a message box with the error.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = GetData("Select * From SomeTable;")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

In your function you are returning a `DataTable` so why are you messing with a `DataSet`? Just load the `DataTable`. `Connection`s, `Command`s, and `DataReader`s all need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle closing and disposing even if there is an error.

```
Public Function GetData(query As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=AS400_CA;UID=root;PWD=*****;"),
        cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(query, cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

this C# code worked for me.

I am using the IBM access client solutions 64bit ODBC driver.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;

namespace IntroUI
{
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

// make sure using 64 bit IBM i Access ODBC driver
  var conn = OpenConnection("dsn", "user", "pass");

  OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  var query = "select  a.* from qrpglesrc a";
  var table = GetData( conn, query ) ;

  var numRows = table.Rows.Count ;
  for( var ix = 0 ; ix < numRows ; ++ix )
  {
    var row = table.Rows[ix] ;
    var srcdta = row.ItemArray[2] ;
    Console.WriteLine( srcdta ) ;
    if ( ix > 20 )
      break ;
  }

  conn.Close( ) ;

  }

  // InDsn is the dsn from the odbc administration window
  static OdbcConnection OpenConnection( string InDsn, string InUser, string InPwd )
    {
      string connString = "DSN=" + InDsn + "; UID=" + InUser +
        "; PWD=" + InPwd + ";" ;
      OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection( connString ) ;
      conn.Open( ) ;
      return conn ;
    }

    static DataTable GetData( OdbcConnection conn, string query )
    {
      OdbcDataAdapter dm = new OdbcDataAdapter() ;
      OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet( ) ;
      dm.SelectCommand = cmd ;
      dm.Fill( ds, "table") ;
      var data = ds.Tables["table"] ;
      return data ;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Many database objects including Connections and Commands need to be disposed. It is nor practical to declare a connection outside of the method where it is used.